# Vue Js Router with Param Producing a Syntaxerror

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am still new to Vue Js. This is a piece of my routes code

```javascript
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import dashboard from './views/dashboard.vue';
import settings from './views/settings.vue';

const title = process.env.VUE_APP_TITLE;

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: dashboard,
    },
    {
      path: '/payments/otherpayments',
      name: 'Other Payments',
    },
    {
      path: '/accounts/banks',
      name: 'Bank Accounts',
    },
    {
      path: '/accounts/payments',
      name: 'Payments',
    },
    {
      path: '/accounts/petty-cash',
      name: 'Petty Cash',
    },
    {
      path: '/accounts/expenses',
      name: 'Expenses',
    },
    {
      path: '/settings/:page?',
      name: 'settings',
      component: settings,
    },
  ],
});
```

I have this strange problem. When I add params to my router, it retruns a page a blank page with  `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`, but when I remove the param part it works fine. I am using typescript. What could be the problem, please.

I know it is not a typing error because the error comes from `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: please update the code to be clear

Comment: this is just a simple vue js router, I removed the unnecessary parts. Thanks

Comment: { path: '/settings/:page', component: settings, name: 'settings' }

Comment: is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: Post your config complete vue-router

Comment: I tried that one before, the current one. This one gives me an option of an empty param

Comment: Show me the return for kindness

Comment: you try just to add `:page` without `?`?

Comment: I tried that, won't work

Comment: could you add `props: true` to your route definition. When props is set to true, the route.params will be set as the component props. You'll need to declare the prop in your component.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [asnwere](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-js-router-with-param-producing-a-syntaxerror/50235/7)

The problem was,  my server configuration fall-back were n not being loaded